# How reset Heroku PG DB via Heroku Scheduler?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku, scheduler

I have demo ROR app in Heroku and I would like to reset PG DB everyday via `Heroku Scheduler`. I have some commands, but I don't know how I can use they in `Heroku Scheduler`. I just paste this, but it don't work for me.

commands:

`heroku restart && heroku pg:reset DATABASE_URL --confirm APP_NAME_ON_HEROKU && heroku run rake db:migrate && heroku run rake db:seed`

Could you please tell me, how I should to use this commands?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for me worked it:

`rake db:schema:load DISABLE_DATABASE_ENVIRONMENT_CHECK=1 && rake db:seed`

UPD:

the commands(`heroku run rake db:migrate`) that I performed early, working only from the Heroku CLI. For Heroku Scheduler we must use these commands without a keywords `heroku run`. `rake db:reset` don't work, disabled on the side Heroku. Also I couldn't use `heroku pg:reset DATABASE_URL --confirm APP_NAME_ON_HEROKU`.

useful links:

1. [How to reset PG Database on Heroku?](https://gist.github.com/zulhfreelancer/ea140d8ef9292fa9165e)
2. [Running Rake Commands](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rake)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [official documentation link](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=heroku%20rake&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8)

You can use the following command below.

```
heroku run rake db:schema:load DISABLE_DATABASE_ENVIRONMENT_CHECK=1  db:seed
```